# Child ScrollView Intercepting/Blocking/Swallowing Clicks to its Parent View

Tags: android, scrollview

Given the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_item"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview_description"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageview_item"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_description"
            style="@style/TextDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In code I've added a OnClickListenter to the parent/container relativeLayout.

```
View itemView = (View) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item);

itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do stuff
    });
```

This works fine if the ImageView is tapped, however if the description ScrollView/TextView area is tapped the OnClickListenter's onClick() method is never fired, presumably because the ScrollView is handling/swallowing the touches.

How can I have standard click events be passed from the ScrollView to ensure its parent relativeLayout OnClickListenter.onClick() method fires instead? (But obviously still have the ScrollView scrollable)

Thanks

Comment: In scroll view Tag of layout, please add android:clickable="false". Please try it and let me know the result

Comment: I am facing same problem. @OliverPearmain If you have got solution, can you post answer??

Answer (score 0):

Declare your ScrollView `non clickable and non focusable` to pass click events to the parentView.

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.  I had already tried the android:clickable="false" as I'd seen this suggested in other answer to a similar question.

Answer (score -1):

`ScrollView` always needs a child as layout. `ScrollView` will never have direct child as View. So create one layout inside scrollview and inside that layout add your `TextView` as below:

Here i have added `LinearLayout` you can add layout according to your choice.

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview_description"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageview_item"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/linerlayout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_description"
        style="@style/TextDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion but unfortunately this doesn't seem to resolve the issue.